Driver using driverKit stop working with iOS 17.4
We have a project that uses a custom driver and has entitlements for DriverKit and DriverKit USB transport.
We do the detection of the device using IOKit but for transferring data we use DriverKit
The app works fine with the device in iOS16, it detects the device and it start the service ( after allowing the driver in the Settings App )
This is not the case with 17.4, it detects the device but the service for the driver won't start.
The driver section in the Settings App for our App shows the toggle to enable the driver in both OS 16 and 17.4
Any ideas of where I can start looking?

Any crash reports? (They should be visible in the Xcode organizer when the iPad is connected to the Mac)

Sorry @pmdj I missed this. I was actually comparing the logs between iPadOS16 and iPadOS17 and there are some differences:
Failed to write application cache:  and then some lines about Saving dextbin info. and then: Saving appproval db, encoding and then Failed to write approval database during state update: 
This is all coming from driverkitd process.
Is there a way to show the private part in the logs? Also do you think this is related with the deployment target in the DriverKit target. In iPadOS16 won't work with all the options ( currently in 21.4)

Here's a quick update. We discovered that the issue is not related to the iOS version but rather the model of the iPads. We tested an M2 iPad Pro running iOS 17 and another running iOS 18, and the drivers are present in the App Settings.
However, on an iPad M4 with the same iOS version (17 and 18) the driver doesn't not appear.
I then tried updating the iPad M4 to iOS18.1 Beta and the driver is back.
I'm unsure it's back because it's a beta version ( there might have fewer restrictions ) or it's back because something was fixed in iOS18.1
